# Extracting splukn data from Python script

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve the data from splunk through python but i get syntax error where as curl command gives me output

```
import requests

baseurl = 'https://*****/services/search/jobs/export'

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

data = {
    'username': '****',
    'password': '*******',
    "search": "search index=sso-fed-prod source="/app/pingfederate-9.3.2/pingfederate/log/splunk-audit.log" event=SSO OR AUTHN_ATTEMPT OR OAuth connectionid status=success",
}

r = requests.get(baseurl, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

output

```
edwops@ip-10-94-202-253:/app/edwops/scripts/python > python splunk_extract.py 
  File "splunk_extract.py", line 12
    "search": "search index=sso-fed-prod source="/app/pingfederate-9.3.2/pingfederate/log/splunk-audit.log" event=SSO OR AUTHN_ATTEMPT OR OAuth connectionid status=success",
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are closing the string with `"` just replace with `"search index=sso-fed-prod source='/app/pingfederate-9.3.2/pingfederate/log/splunk-audit.log' event=SSO OR AUTHN_ATTEMPT OR OAuth connectionid status=success"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the generation of data dict, try:

```py
data = {
    'username': '****',
    'password': '*******',
    "search": 'search index=sso-fed-prod source="/app/pingfederate-9.3.2/pingfederate/log/splunk-audit.log" event=SSO OR AUTHN_ATTEMPT OR OAuth connectionid status=success',
}
```

Explanation: when you set up value for `search` key, you close quotation marks `"` here:

```
search index=sso-fed-prod source="
```

so all what goes after is assumed to be a variable by an interpreatator and not the string as intended. So you just need to use single quotation marks `'` for the whole `search` value.

Comment: Thays Awsome it worked but i have imported json i am gettinng the below error

Comment: File "splunk_extract.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(r.json())
  File "/app/edwops/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: PLease note python 3.6.2>  
>   "chardet": {
>     "version": "3.0.4"
>   },
>   "cryptography": {
>     "version": "2.0.3"
>   },
>   "idna": {
>     "version": ""
>   },
>   "implementation": {
>     "name": "CPython",
>     "version": "3.6.2"
>   },
>   "platform": {
>     "release": "16.7.0",
>     "system": "Darwin"
>   },
>   "pyOpenSSL": {
>     "openssl_version": "100020cf",
>     "version": "17.2.0"
>   },
>   "requests": {
>     "version": "2.18.4"
>   },
>   "system_ssl": {
>     "version": "100020cf"
>   },
>   "urllib3": {
>     "version": "1.22"
>

Comment: @sohinis. Did you solve your problem? I am interested in the solution.